# ForbidAsync Vs ChallengeAsync why and when to use them

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

There are two method on `AuthenticationManager` class, `ForbidAsync()` and `ChallengeAsync()`, I know that I can execute `HttpContext.Authentication.ForbidAsync` or return a result of type `ForbidResult` in my controller and it has the same effect, same is true for `ChallengeAsync`. But it seems that they produce the same result:

```
public ForbidResult ForbidResult()
{
  return Forbid();
}

public ChallengeResult ChallengeResult()
{
  return Challenge();
}
```

[image: ForbidAsync Vs ChallengeAsync]
There are not much documentation on the use of them or any example at this point, I was wondering how and why to use them.

**Update**: By the way, I complied my research in this area to an article by the name of [Asp.Net Core Action Results Explained](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/03/29/asp-net-core-action-results-explained/).

Comment: Are you calling challenge for an authenticated user? That may explain the forbidden. It's there to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A challenge result should generally be used in cases where the current visitor is not logged in, but is trying to access an action that requires an authenticated user. It will prompt a challenge for credentials. It could also be used for an authenticated user, who is not authorised for the action, and where you want to prompt for higher privileged credentials.

A forbid result should be used in cases where the current visitor is logged in as a user in your system, but is trying to access an action that their account does not have permission to perform.

With the standard ASP.NET Core CookieAuthentication added by Identity, default paths are set to handle each case and the user gets redirected.

By default...
Access denied - i.e. forbidden looks to redirect to /Account/AccessDenied
Unauthenticated - i.e. challenge looks to redirect to /Account/Login

Without redirection, forbidden will return a 403 status code, challenge will return a 401.

In your case, as redirects are occurring as specified in the default options, you're seeing the 302 found status codes instead.

I've not looked deep into code around this, but that's my general understanding.